# Is it more efficient to assign data from a structure once, or to extract it multiple times?

Tags: matlab, performance, data-structures

I have to run a certain functions many times; this function takes a certain structure `sc` as input. Within the function, certain values from the structure (say `sc.a` and `sc.b`) are used multiple times.

I have two options:

1. Assign `a=sc.a` and use `a` every time it is needed within the function;
2. Extract `sc.a` every time I need it within the function.

Which of these is more efficient? In (1) I am using extra memory to assign `a`, while in (2) I am extracting `sc.a` multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried testing it? In any case, it always better to avoid structures if you need to do it a lot, they are slower

Comment: Would arrays be much faster? As in, instead of calling `a=sc.a`, I would call `a=sc(1)`

Comment: Yes, they would, quite faster if you have a lot of operations

Comment: The best way to know is to implement both options, and use `timeit` to see the difference. Note that `a=sc.a` doesn't copy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays would quite faster if you have a plenty of operations.

This is almost language agnostic. Arrays are easier to access due to being next to each other in memory, while with structs you break the memory pattern, so you disable the possibility of caching, thus requiring more time for memory reads. On top of that, MATLAB's openMP/multi-thread operations work great in arrays, while they don't in structs.